# Процесс загрузки видео (ffmpeg, jquery)

Tags: jquery, php, видео

Пользователи загружают видео на сайте. `Ffmpeg` его кодирует.
Можно ли сделать процесс, чтобы пользователям было не скучно

Answer (score 3):

Например через `cron` сделать кодирование. И пользователям не придется ждать, они смогу просматривать другие страницы сайта, либо вообще закрыть браузер. По окончании задания сделать видео доступным для просмотра. А пока оно кодируется - выводит какое то сообщение, типа "Видео обрабатывается"

Comment: особенно если видео большое, а сервер слабенький

Comment: Спасибо, пацаны! 
А чтобы загрузку сделать.... эт не стоит того?)

Comment: Ну так загрузка в большинстве случаев быстро происходит. Основное время занимает кодирование. Что вы конкретно хотите и в какой момент?

Comment: человек выбирает видео для загрузки. допустим, видео 10 мб. пока эти 10 мб. загружаются, человек видит проценты загрузки это видео на сервер, после чего текст "Выше видео обрабатывается!" и он идет гулять!

Comment: В моем ответе как раз эта схема и описана. Если Вас не устраивает стандартный загрузчик, то попробуйте SWFUploader, там можно допилить шкалу загрузки как Вам надо. А само видео после загрузки по крону кодировать уже

Comment: насчет крона можно чуть подробнее, плиз?

Comment: В базе данных создаете таблицу, в которую будете добавлять задания для крона. Сам скрипт по крону пинать допустим раз в минуту, смотреть, есть ли задания. Если есть, то запускать задание. Например при загрузке добавить таск processVideo, и указать имя файла. Потом в кроне запустить эту же функцию и файл с указанным именем перекодировать. Как пользоваться кроном это уже другой вопрос. Думаю в гугле найдете, ничего военного нету

Comment: Спасибо огромное за инфо!